# Making a SCSS mixin with an optional argument that is passed to the property name

Tags: variables, sass, option-type

I have been reading through [a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689152/how-to-pass-a-property-name-as-an-argument-to-a-mixin-in-less) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512802/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-sass) [answers](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments) but none of these help me where I need it.

I want to write a rule for borders that consist of three variables. The first is optional and makes clear which side the border should be on (top, right, bottom or left; if not present the default should simply be `border:`). The second one defines the width of the border and the latter the colour. I tried something like [this](http://sassmeister.com/gist/bc0d504460646e2da8b7). But that doesn't work unfortunately, because I don't provide a third argument I am guessing.

```
@mixin border($direction,$size,$colour) {
    @if variable-exists($direction) {
        border-#{$direction}: $size solid $colour;
    } @else {
        border: $size solid $colour;
    }
}
$borderradius: 2px;
$borderSize: 1px;
$mainColour: #ccc;
$hoverColour: #4679bd;

@include border($borderSize, $mainColour);
```

Comment: Why would you do this?  Using this mixin is *more* verbose than just using straight CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this solution. By adding the optional variable at the end of your arguments. Keep in mind that you have to place the optional variable last in your arguments order.

```
@mixin border($size, $colour, $direction:"") {
  @if $direction != "" {
    border-#{$direction}: $size solid $colour;
  }

  @else {
    border: $size solid $colour;
  }
}

$borderradius: 2px;
$borderSize: 1px;
$mainColour: #ccc;
$hoverColour: #4679bd;

div {
  @include border($borderSize, $mainColour);
}
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/560cb13c92498d6d39e6

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain a bit? What does `:""` do in the mixin?

Comment: @BramVanroy `:""` means that it's an empty optional variable (variable doesn't exist). So if the $direction != (is not) empty use $direction variable else ignore it. Hope that this helped :)