# Check if SASS Map exists

Tags: sass, sass-maps

How do I check if a SASS Map already exists and only define one if this is not the case?

I have tried:

```
@if ($myMap) {
// do something
}
```

and

```
@if variable-exists($myMap) {
// do something
}
```

But I get the error `Undefined variable: "$myMap"`?

I'm sure this is pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to find the answer online?

Comment: Perhaps try without the `$` in the if statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237776/3909886

Comment: But the name of the map has a $ so its needed?!

Answer (score 2):

It's a little confusing, but when checking for a variable's existence, skip the `$`. You also need to set it as a global variable so it doesn't get scoped only to the `@if` block. This works:

```scss
@if variable-exists(myMap) == false {
  $myMap: (
    1: "foo",
    2: "bar"
  ) !global;
}

// ... now you can use your variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the map to exist as null be default, which means that if it isn't explicitly set anywhere, then the variable still exists but with a null value. You can then check if the value of the variable is null using an if statement.

```css
$myMap: null !default;

@if $myMap == null {
  
}
```