# @if SASS condition if background color using match --variable

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

i tried to make a condition on my component with sass @if and @else which is if `background == var(--bg-danger)` color return is white like this, but it just read white result not else condition

```
@mixin text-color
  @if (background: var(--bg-danger))
    color: var(--text-white)
  @else
    color: var(--text-dark)
```

hope you guys give me a solution, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question has an answer: you need to have `==` inside if statement, not `:`.

If you want to check if a certain variable use a **variable-exists()** function, see: [Checking if a variable is defined in SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512802/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-sass)