# How to check in SCSS if a variable exists and ha a value?

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I am new in SCSS so bear with me :)

I have a use case where a SCSS variable `--my-variable` can exist and can have a value depending on some settings from the backend. So, if `--my-variable` exists and has a value I should override some styling. If not I shouldn't override anything.

**Example:**

In file1 I have:

```
.my-div {
    color: red;
    }
```

In file2 I should have something like this:

```
.my-div {
@include customize(color, --my-variable);
}

@mixin customize($property, $variable) {
  @if $variable and (var($variable)) {
    #{$property}: var($variable);
  }
}
```

**The problem is** that the `if` condition inside the mixin `customize()` is always true even if my document has no CSS variable called `--my-variable`. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: As of Sass 3.3 there is a variable-exists() function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a variable is defined in SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512802/checking-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-sass)

Answer (score 0):

Sass has a function that check if the variable exists.

`variable-exists()`

```
$colorVariable: crimson;

@if variable-exists($colorVariable) {
   // Do some styling if the variable exists
}
```